# Promises: some problems with reject

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have an issue with promise in 'Angular 2'.

Please see my code below:

```
getPromise1().then((result) => { 
        console.log("promise1 result"); 
    }, (error) => { 
        console.log("promise1 error"); 
    });

function getPromise1() {
    return getPromise2().then((result) => {
        console.log("promise2 result");
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("promise2 error");
    });

}

function getPromise2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject("error");
    });
}
```

And the result is: `promise2 error` and `promise1 result`. 
I don't know why not `promise2 error` and `promise1 error` 
Any problem and the solution for this case? 
This is preview link: http://plnkr.co/edit/RTc1wYfO8e1YPUrXM6GN

Comment: Because once you handle the rejection the resulting promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a promise rejects, **the control jumps to the closest rejection handler down the chain**.

so, Here the `.catch` block finishes normally. So the next successful handler is called. Or it could return something, that would be the same.

Hence the result

> And the result is: `promise2 error` and `promise1 result`.

So you could have as many .then as we want, and then use a single .catch at the end to handle errors in all of them.

But to get the following result

> I don't know why not `promise2 error` and `promise1 error`

you need to re-throw the error

```
throw error;
```

And here the .catch block analyzes the error and throws it again:

```
function getPromise1() {
    return getPromise2().then((result) => {
        console.log("promise2 result");
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("promise2 error");
        throw error;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, great for me. And I have one more question, the promise will keep a connection or not. For ex: if I return the promise but I don't reject or resolve, any problem for getPromise1 or getPromise2 function?

Comment: What do you mean by `promise will keep a connection or not.` 
Failing to resolve or reject a promise just fails to ever change the state from *pending* to anything else. Hence, Any `.then()` listeners for resolve or reject transitions will never get called.

Comment: Thanks, this is the info that I want. I'm afraid that if many promises are waiting, maybe make the performance slow or the promise maybe auto resolve ... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you handle a rejection in any promise chain then that's going to make the resulting chain to be fulfilled until an error is found then it goes back to being rejected. Think about it in terms of sync code, would you have expected this to print `error A` and `error B`?

```
function myFnA(){
    throw new Error('A is bad');
}

function myFnB(){
   try {
      myFnA();
      console.log('good A');
   } catch(e){
      console.log('error A');
   }
}

function myFnC(){
   try {
      myFnB();
      console.log('good B');
   }
   catch(e){
      console.log('error B');
   }
}

myFnC();
```

`myFnB` fixes `myFnA` error. So `myFnB` is doing it's job right.